# How to fill between two AreaCharts in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, charts

The Area Chart in JavaFX fills the area between the data line and the zero y-axis.

I would only like to know how to fill between two Area Charts.

More Details:

I am generating a bunch of random walks. Then, I create three different XYCharts for the Paths, the mean, and the mean +/- std. deviation. Finally, I use a StackPane to place each chart on top of each other with transparent background.

The order of the charts has to be the following:
1. Simulated paths chart on the very back (LineChart).
2. Std. Deviation chart (AreaChart).
3. The mean chart on top (LineChart).

Pictures - highlighting the problem.

[image]
[image]

How can I accomplish this? CSS is preferred.

Comment: Maybe you can play with -fx-blend-mode property.

Comment: @whitesite thank you but I could not fix it with blend-mode either

Comment: I tried building a polygon as well but .getDisplayPosition() is not returning the right values for some reason. I am not doing it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to achieve the result using `-fx-blend-mode` property. Here is an example for two area charts:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    stage.setTitle("Test");
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("X");
    final AreaChart<Number,Number> lineChart =
            new AreaChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

    lineChart.setTitle("Test");

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("S1");
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, 0));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 20));

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName("S2");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, 0));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(20, 10));

    Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1,series2);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/test.css");
    stage.show();
}
```

And the css in `test.css`:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-area-fill {
    -fx-fill: #FF0000;
    -fx-blend-mode: difference;
}
.default-color1.chart-series-area-fill {
    -fx-fill: #FF0000;
    -fx-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

And the result:
[image: Result]
**Edit**
CSS for screen/multiply:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-area-fill {
    -fx-fill: rgb(0,178,0);
    -fx-blend-mode: screen;
}

.default-color1.chart-series-area-fill {
    -fx-fill: rgb(255,246,255);
    -fx-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Result:[image: Screen/multiply]

Comment: Thank you so much! Works beautiful.

Comment: When I try to change the fill color it doesn't work anymore (other than  #FF0000). Can you tell me why please?

Comment: @EdvBeq I'm not a blend expert, but all it's just a plain math. Blending mode 'difference' is taking bottom and top input colors and subtracts smaller value from bigger. It means that if you pass 1 (or FF in hex) you get inverted color, 0 gives you the same color.  So passing 1 for a color channel in first area chart we get inverted chart plot background color. Passing 1 for the second area chart we get inverted color again, which gives us the original chart plot background. Other modes (i.e. screen and multiply) can give the similar result (see edit), but you need to calculate proper values.