# How to shade the area between two area chart lines in Javafx. PFA the expected behaviour image

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

[image: I am working on a javafx chart projec]
I am working on a javafx chart project which needs to draw multiple area charts(or line charts) and the intersection between two lines must be shaded with a particular color.

Comment: any one please ?

Comment: I have successfully tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38412470/how-to-fill-between-two-areacharts-in-javafx  this solution. But by this solution its not possible to shade with a user choosen color.